# Excel InStr Function opposite direction

Tags: vba, function, excel

I have this VBA code that I am using to compare two columns in my Excel spreadsheet, column B to column A.  It then "highlights" the ones that are missing from column A but in column B.

What I can't figure out is how to reverse the procedure to search column B and highlight the ones in column A that are different.

Original Code:

```
For i = 2 To LastRow
    For j = 2 To LastRow
        If Report.Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" Then 'This will omit blank cells at the end (in the event that the column lengths are not equal.
            If InStr(1, Report.Cells(j, 1).Value, Report.Cells(i, 2).Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                Report.Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = xlNone 'Transparent background
                Report.Cells(i, 2).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'Black font color
                Exit For
            Else
                Report.Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(156, 0, 6) 'Dark red background
                Report.Cells(i, 2).Font.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206) 'Light red font color
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

I have tried renaming the letters and switching the column values and got close but realized that it was using the values from the original search and just highlighting the corresponding cells in column A.

Comment: Is there a reason you do not want to use conditional formatting to do this?

Comment: What is `Report`? A `Worksheet`?

Comment: To piggy-back on @ScottCraner, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34005669/excel-conditional-formatting-two-lists-on-different-spreadsheets) for a conditional formatting solution.

Comment: `=And(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,B:B,1,False)) = FALSE, A1 <> "")` Is the formula I would use for conditional formatting.

Comment: I was going to do that but this is just a piece of a bigger VBA structure that creates an elaborate workbook solution and outputs data that end-users can see without anything more than pressing a button.

Comment: You could still use conditional formatting, just set it up with VB instead of manually. (Unless I'm missing something...)

Comment: Yes. **Report.** is SET to a Worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:

```
For j = 2 To LastRow
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Report.Cells(j, 1).Value <> "" Then 'This will omit blank cells at the end (in the event that the column lengths are not equal.
            If InStr(1, Report.Cells(i, 2).Value, Report.Cells(j, 1).Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                Report.Cells(j, 1).Interior.Color = xlNone 'Transparent background
                Report.Cells(j, 1).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'Black font color
                Exit For
            Else
                Report.Cells(j, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(156, 0, 6) 'Dark red background
                Report.Cells(j, 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206) 'Light red font color
            End If
        End If
    Next i
Next j
```

If you wanted to used conditional formatting which makes the color changes live you can replace both loop with:

```
With Report.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).FormatConditions
    .Delete
    With .Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=And(iserror(Vlookup(A2,B:B,1,False)),A2<>"""")")
        .Font.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206)
        .Interior.Color = RGB(156, 0, 6)
    End With
End With
With Report.Range("B2:B" & LastRow).FormatConditions
    .Delete
    With .Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=And(iserror(Vlookup(B2,A:A,1,False)),B2<>"""")")
        .Font.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206)
        .Interior.Color = RGB(156, 0, 6)
    End With
End With
```

Edit the issue was that the data in Column A had an extra space at the end thus making the instr to return false.

```
For j = 2 To LastRow
    Report.Cells(j, 1).Value = Trim(Report.Cells(j, 1).Value)
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        Report.Cells(i, 2).Value = Trim(Report.Cells(i, 2).Value)
        If Report.Cells(j, 1).Value <> "" Then 'This will omit blank cells at the end (in the event that the column lengths are not equal.
            If InStr(1, Report.Cells(i, 2).Value, Report.Cells(j, 1).Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                Report.Cells(j, 1).Interior.Color = xlNone 'Transparent background
                Report.Cells(j, 1).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'Black font color
                Exit For
            Else
                Report.Cells(j, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(156, 0, 6) 'Dark red background
                Report.Cells(j, 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206) 'Light red font color
            End If
        End If
    Next i
Next j
```

By trimming the values, the instr returned true.

Comment: I have copied and pasted and it colors all the cells in each column.

Comment: @JustinTriadTechx So since both methods, mine and jspek, I would assume that your data is not identical.  Could you post in your original post an example of the data being tested?  Going by what you have they should work.

Comment: Would it have anything to do with me pulling data in from an outside source?  I can't share it because it is confidential information.  I will try to create a dummy worksheet and share it.

Comment: Here is a link to a dummy database setup exactly like the other data: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-r3owCpuUY-QVoyTDFFbnpQcnM&usp=sharing

Comment: I would need data that matches closely what you are testing.  An empty sheet template does me no good.  The issue is with the data that you are trying to test.

Comment: The template should have two datasheets that import into it when it is opened.  I tested it before I sent you the link and it worked just fine.  If you want me to embed the data into the template I will, but it's not setup that way originally.

Comment: @JustinTriadTechx Without data that closely matches what you are testing how can I find the problem? Also I do not have the rest of your code, so the snippets will not work as they refer to variable I would presume get set earlier in existing code. I can input data but it will work because I will put in data that works. I need to see something of yours to see why it doesn't.

Comment: Try the link now... there should be data in the table and I included the code that is contained in my macro as a separate document.  The data in the sheet is an exact copy, except the names have been changed.

Comment: @JustinTriadTechx I see it now, I am stepping into a meeting that will take the rest of the afternoon, I will look at it when i get home tonight.

Comment: Not a problem... thank you for your help and sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish this. 
You could use formulas, you could create dictionaries.

A Quick solution would be:

```
    Dim stringCount As Integer
    Dim myString As String
    Dim col1Range As Range
    Dim col2Range As Range

    Set col1Range = Report.Range("A1")
    Set col2Range = Report.Range("B1")

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        myString = col1Range.Offset(i).Value

        If myString <> "" Then
            stringCount = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B:B"), myString)

            If (stringCount = 0) Then
                col1Range.Offset(i).Interior.Color = RGB(156, 0, 6) 'Dark red background
                col1Range.Offset(i).Font.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206) 'Light red font color
            Else
                col1Range.Offset(i).Interior.Color = xlNone 'Transparent background
                col1Range.Offset(i).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'Black font color
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    For j = 1 To LastRow
        myString = col2Range.Offset(j).Value

        If myString <> "" Then
            stringCount = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), myString)

            If (stringCount = 0) Then
                col2Range.Offset(j).Interior.Color = RGB(156, 0, 6) 'Dark red background
                col2Range.Offset(j).Font.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206) 'Light red font color
            Else
                col2Range.Offset(j).Interior.Color = xlNone 'Transparent background
                col2Range.Offset(j).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'Black font color
            End If
        End If
    Next j
```

Comment: I have copied and pasted and it colors all the cells in each column.